# Estimating number of possible linear combinations with restriction on coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n, c, d$ be positive real numbers. I am trying to get a sharp estimate on the number of possible linear combinations lying between $c$ and $d$, that is,
$$
c < a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n < d
$$
such that $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are nonnegative integers. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the number of lattice points in the first octant between two parallel hyperplanes. So a good estimate can be obtained by subtracting good upper and lower bounds on the volume of a simplex bounded by one such plane ...

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail.